# adding an action button to a second toolbar

Tags: android

I have an app with two toolbars. The first one is inflated accordingly, the second one has a textview. I'd like to add an action button to second one, to the right. Similar to what the youtube app does.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewWebPage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Use Toolbar#inflateMenu(R.menu.your_menu) method

Comment: How do I detect when a button is clicked. Adding code to onOptionsItemSelected() doesn't work.

Comment: I used `setOnMenuItemClickListener` and it's working